# Помогите понять не сложный PHP

Tags: php

Я в PHP вообще ни бум-бум. JS немного шарю. 
Помогите понять что тут происходит.

```php
    global $data;
    $data=array();

    $data["th"]=array();
    $data["th"][0]=array("name"=>"Автовышки","name1"=>"автовышек","name2"=>"автовышки","alias"=>"avtovyshki");
    $data["th"][1]=array("name"=>"Автокраны","name1"=>"автокранов","name2"=>"автокрана","alias"=>"avtokrany");
    $data["th"][2]=array("name"=>"Бульдозеры","name1"=>"бульдозеров","name2"=>"бульдозера","alias"=>"buldozery");

    $data["teh"]=array();
    foreach($data["th"] as $t)
    {
    $data["teh"][$t["alias"]]=$t;
    }
```

По сути он создал Массив "data", внутри этого массива еще 2 массива "th" и "teh".
Внутри "th" еще массивы, с этим все ясно.

Непонятня ситуация, когда он начинает перебирать массив "th" и присваивать каждый его элемент $t. 
А далее:

```
$data["teh"][$t["alias"]]=$t;
```

Как понять?

И еще:

```
global $data;
```

Я правильно понимаю, что для того чтобы использовать эти данные в другом php файле нужно как то подключить данный файл, с помощью require или include?
Так как очень долго искал где же подключается этот файл (data.php), но так и не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С конца:

```
global $data;
```

Слишком мало информации, но с уверенностью в `99%` можно сказать что ваш кусок - это тело функции... Видимо тот кто писал, хочет чтоб манипуляции были с переменной которую дальше ведет по программе (а именно `$data`). Это плохой тон программирования, слишком много минусов у такого подхода, использовать не рекомендую.

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function test_func() {
    global $a;

    echo $a; // - Выведет 1
    echo $b; // - Ничего не выведет, будешь предупреждение что переменная не существует
}
test_func();
```

По поводу использования данных в других файлах, вам нужно почитать вот это:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php

Там все в примерчиках...

---

Теперь ко второму:

```
$data["teh"][$t["alias"]]=$t;
```

У нас есть массив $data["th"]:

```
$data["th"]    = array();
$data["th"][0] = ...
$data["th"][1] = ...
$data["th"][2] = ...
```

С этим Вам вроде все понятно, дальше в цикле мы перебираем этот массив и каждый элемент поочередно присваиваем в `$t`, Вам тоже это понятно, давайте на первом элементе разберем, т.е. на первой итерации цикла у Вас:

```
$t = array(
    "name" => "Автовышки",
    "name1" => "автовышек",
    "name2" => "автовышки",
    "alias" => "avtovyshki"
);
```

Собственно, чтобы вывести на экран `avtovyshki`, нам нужно написать `echo $t["alias"]`. Так-же вы правильно заметили что создается массив `teh`, тут - `$data["teh"]=array()`.

А теперь смотрите:

```
$data["teh"][$t["alias"]]=$t;
```

Для первой итерации выглядит так:

```
$data["teh"]["avtovyshki"] = array(
    "name" => "Автовышки",
    "name1" => "автовышек",
    "name2" => "автовышки",
    "alias" => "avtovyshki"
);
```

Все переменные я вам показал выше, простая постановка :) ...